# How do I scroll to a newly appended list element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm appending a new list item and trying to scroll it into view.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="slim-scrollbar">
  <ul class="chats">
    <li class="out">dynamic text with variable lengths</li>
    <li class="in">dynamic text with variable lengths</li>
    <li class="in">dynamic text with variable lengths</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My current jquery to append an item to the list:

```
var direction='out';

$('.chats').append('<li class="'+direction+'">'+textVar+'</li>');
```

My jquery attempt:

```
    $(".chats").animate({
        scrollTop: ???
    }, 1000);
```

How do I scroll the new list element into view?

Comment: What's the code you're using to scroll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use your code, this should work:

```
$('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.chats li:last-child').offset().top + 'px'
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This isn't working...I'm using the slim scrollbar plugin (http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) so this might be causing an issue

Comment: @Paul If you have this in a scrollable container than you must use: `$([container]).animate();` and `$('.chats li:last-child').position().top`.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Ive tried it but doesnt work (at a glance in the answer you need to close some brackets, but even with that it doesnt works for me, it gives me an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." in the second .animate part)

Comment: @Yises Hm, there was some strange thing in the answer since the last edit. I fixed it. Hope it works for you as well now.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a cleaner solution:

```
var direction = 'out',
    lastLi = $("<li/>", {
        class: direction,
        text: textVar
    }).appendTo('.cheats');
$(document).animate({
    scrollTop: lastLi.offset().top + 'px'
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: make sure you've got the [`scrollTo()` plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) installed.

Step 2: Save the appended object in a temporary variable, then scroll the body (or parent div, if in a scrollable div).

```
var newelem = $('<li class="'+direction+'">'+textVar+'</li>');
$('.chats').append(newelem);
$('body').scrollTo(newelem);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an option for you if you really need to use the jQuery animation, but, you could also give your list an id and then use native functionality to get the user to the newly added content.

```
<ul id="new-stuff" class="chats">

//Append the element and all that good stuff.

location.hash = '#new-stuff';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is inside a wrapper div with some height.

```
<div id="chatsWrapper" style="height: 200px; overflow:auto;">
<ul class="chats">
  <li class="out">dynamic text with variable lengths</li>
  <li class="in">dynamic text with variable lengths</li>
  <li class="in">dynamic text with variable lengths</li>
</ul>
</div>

$('.chats').append('<li class="'+direction+'">'+textVar+'</li>');
```

Just animate the wrapper div to an arbitrarily high pixel value:

```
$('#chatsWrapper').animate({ scrollTop: 10000 }, 'normal');
```